# Fillling drop down box from BLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How to fill DropDown from database ? I Have UI and BLL layer and sp but can't fill it. Drop down name is  "DrpdwnComplainantTypes". I have done this type of things many times but not this time. Help please.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ComplainantBizz comBizz = new ComplainantBizz(txtName.Text, txtCNIC.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtContact.Text, Convert.ToInt32(DropdwnCompType.SelectedValue));
            ManageComplainant mngComplainantType = new ManageComplainant();

            bool Result = mngComplainantType.Insert(comBizz);


            if (Result == true)
            {
                HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "Saved";
                HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
                Clear(txtName);
            }
            else
            {
                HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "RecordAlreadyExists";
                HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HiddenFieldSetMessage.Value = "NotSaved";
            HiddenFieldShowMessage.Value = "True";
        }
    }
```

BLL:

```
public DataTable FillDropDown()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectAllComplainants_SP", DataBaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //SqlParameter pName = new SqlParameter("@Name", comBizz.Name);
            //cmd.Parameters.Add(pName);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataBaseConnection.CloseConnection();
            return ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

SP:
This is SP which i am calling.

```
 alter  PROCEDURE SelectAllComplainantTypes_SP


AS
BEGIN

    Begin Try
      Select * from ComplainantTypes 
    End Try
    Begin Catch
     Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMsg
    End Catch

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind datatable return from your function to dropdownlist like in

```
dropdonlist.datasource=FillDropDown();
dropdownlist.datatextfield="yourTextColum";//in example column name "City"
dropdownlist.dataValueFiedl="yourValueColumn";//in example cloum name "ID"
dropdownlist.databind();
```

that's all

Note: if you will return null from your function you throw an exception, if no data has been return  no data will show in dropdownlist